# a4j:jsFunction oncomplete does not fire

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to call a javascript method, when the aj4:jsFunction request is completed. But somehow the method defined by oncomplete does not work.

Here's the jsf code:

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="createEvent"
        data="#{calendarController.eventId}" oncomplete="alert('hi')">
        <a4j:param name="eventTitle"
            assignTo="#{calendarController.eventTitle}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</h:form>
```

If I call the method createEvent(eventTitle), the getter of the eventId property is called, but not the js code "alert('hi')".

Here's the bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CalendarController {

    private int eventId;
    private String eventTitle;

    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    public String getEventTitle() {
        return eventTitle;
    }

    public void setEventTitle(String eventTitle) {
        this.eventTitle = eventTitle;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions why the oncomplete method is not called?

Comment: How do you call the function in JavaScript? I suspect that AJAX request is not sent at all.

Comment: I call it like this: createEvent(eventTitle);

Comment: I agree with @skuntsel - are you sure that `setEventTitle` gets called? If you call it like: `createEvent(eventTitle)` then `eventTitle` is some string variable, right? Do you get any client side errors?

Comment: Show us the part of the code that actually calls the function. The problem is probably there.

Comment: Yes, it's a string. I debugged the bean and the setter get's called. The getter vor eventId get's called too. In the javascript console there are no errors.

Comment: I don't think your way of calling has anything to do with the problem since your getters are called correctly. Is that all in your `h:form`? No other elements that could cause a validation error? Have you tried with `immediate=true` on `a4j:jsFunction`? Also, is your `setEventTitle()` getting called?

Comment: I call the method when clicking on a day of the fullcalendar.              `select : function(start, end,allDay) {          var title = prompt('Event Title:');           if (title) {              createEvent(title);            }            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');              }` And yes, the a4j:jsFunction is in an h:form

Comment: Ok, I have a (probably dumb) question: don't you have [alerts blocked](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/alertstopper/)? I mean if you run `alert('hi')` then does it work? Also I would try `oncomplete="alert(123);"` - maybe the quotes get rendered incorrectly by some chance.

Comment: You can also test with <a4j:log /> if there is no ajax error.

Comment: No, alerts are not blocked. `oncomplete="alert(123);"` and `immediate=true` doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: Well, here's the a4j:log _warn [18:26:06.345]: richfaces.queue: ajax submit error
error[18:26:06.345]: Received 'error@malformedXML' event from <span id=j_id_s:j_id_t ...>
error[18:26:06.345]: [200] undefined: undefined
info [18:26:06.346]: Received 'complete' event from <span id=j_id_s:j_id_t ...>_

Comment: What can be the reason for getting the ajax submit error?

Comment: Alright, finally figured it out.. Had omnifaces in use with richfaces what apparently lead to ajax failure.